# nginx multisite redirects on different site

Tags: nginx

in sites-enabled file test.com.conf:

```
map $http_host $blogid {
 default 0;
 test.com 1;
}
server {
listen 5.187.1.93:80;
 server_name test.com *.test.com;
 root /home/fornex/wordpress;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/test.com-access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/test.com-error.log;
 include conf.d/restrictions.conf;
# include /home/fornex/wordpress/nginx.conf;
 include conf.d/wordpress-mu.conf;
}
```

file site.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen 5.187.1.93:80;
    server_name site.com *.site.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 5.187.1.93:443 ssl;
   ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
   ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem;

   server_name site.com *.site.com;
   root  /home/fornex/site.com;
   index index.php;

   client_max_body_size 7m;

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }

   location ~*\.(php)$ {
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

when I open test.com(It should be a wordpress installation) - site.com opens. What is wrong? How can I make them separate sites? I searched a lot in WEB but didn't find anything that helps in my situation. Adding `*.test.com` didn't help.

Comment: If you are accessing your `test.com` site via HTTPS, the `site.com` server block will serve that request since it is the only server block listening on 443 TCP port.

Comment: @IvanShatsky so what should I do? Is it necessarily to make ssl for test.com to access this site?

Comment: Right now your `test.com` site should be accessible over the plain HTTP protocol, and if you explicitly type `http://test.com` in the browser address bar, you should access it. To make it accessible over the HTTPS you'll need the second `server` block listening on port 443.

Comment: I couldn't access site with http://test.com (blank page). When I made ssl - I cannot access http at all now (error 500). When I checked certificate on www.ssllabs.com - It's name was *.site.com. 2 domains are for one site. What should I do and why is that happening?

Comment: Error 500 can happened if you got an infinite redirection loop. Check the corresponding message from the error log. I don't know how do you "made ssl", I don't know what do you have inside those `restrictions.conf` and `wordpress-mu.conf` files. You'll get an infinite redirection loop if you put `return 301 http://$host$request_uri;` instead of `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` in your HTTP server block or there can be a couple of other reasons. And of course you need a cert/key for you second domain if you want to use it over SSL.

Comment: Now `http://test.com` redirects on `https://test.com` which is `site.com`

Comment: I made ssl certificate with letsencrypt and checked it

Comment: I deleted those files